# MSSQL - Replace string and update result into another table

Tags: replace, split, set, substring, declare

I want to do something like that:

```
declare @manufacture varchar(MAX)
declare @model varchar(MAX)
declare @version varchar(MAX)
declare @fipeId varchar(MAX)
set @manufacture = (select top 1 MarcaFipe from fipeNew where ModeloFipe like 'Palio%' group by MarcaFipe)
set @model = (select ModeloFipe replace(fipeNew.ModeloFipe, '%', 'Palio') from fipeNew where ModeloFipe like 'Palio%')
set @version = (replace(fipeNew.ModeloFipe, 'Palio ', '') from fipeNew where ModeloFipe like 'Palio%')
set @fipeId = (select CodigoFipe from fipeNew where ModeloFipe like 'Palio%')

UPDATE vehicle
SET vehicle.manufacture=@manufacture,
vehicle.model=@model,
vehicle.version=@version,
vehicle.fipeId=@fipeID
```

In short, I have the following table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brvvo.png

Note: Couldn't post image because of my reputation.

I want to split the dbo.newFipe.ModeloFipe that has string like 'Palio%' and MarcaFipe='Fiat' and set the first word (Palio in this case) into dbo.vehicle.model and the rest of the substring into dbo.vehicle.version.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert into two tables in one statement.

You can use this query to get your values for insert:

```
select distinct left(ModeloFipe,charindex(' ',ModeloFipe)) as Model, right(ModeloFipe,len(ModeloFipe)-charindex(' ',ModeloFipe)) as Version
from dbo.newFipe
where ModeloFipe like 'Palio%' and MarcaFipe='Fiat'
```